# Emberjs: Get the current element

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for something that's similar to the `this` of `jQuery`. I'm going to list below the code I have:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="uiMainContainerTaskList">
    <div class="uiMainContainerTaskListContent">
    {{#view App.TasksView}}
    {{#each App.tasksController.tasks}}
    <div class="uiMainContainerWideItem" {{action "taskClick" target="TasksView" on="click"}}>
        <div class="uiMainContainerWideItemCheckbox">{{view Em.Checkbox checkedBinding="isDone"}}</div>
        <div class="uiMainContainerWideItemText uiMainContainerWideItemTaskName">{{taskName}}</div>
        <div class="uiMainContainerWideItemText uiMainContainerWideItemTaskDescription">{{taskDescription}}</div>
        <div class="uiMainContainerWideItemText uiMainContainerWideItemTaskPriority">{{priority}}</div>
        <div class="uiMainContainerWideItemText uiMainContainerWideItemTaskDueDate">{{dueDate}}</div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
    </div>
</script>
```

I bind the `taskClick` action to the `div.uiMainContainerWideItem`. In my `View` I have:

```
App.TasksView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'uiMainContainerTaskList',
        taskClick: function(e) {
            console.log($(this)); 
        }
});
```

In `jQuery`, `$(this)` would be the current element (no children). Is there a way to get the current element in Ember as well?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`this.$()`](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ViewMixin.html#method__).

Comment: one problem. It returns `<div class="uiMainContainerTaskListContent">` instead of the current `<div class="uiMainContainerWideItem">`(which is the element that I bind the action to).

Comment: solved. I added the declaration of the view inside the each block. Now it returns the current div. Thanks for the information above :)

Comment: Could you provide more details on this, @Andrew? I can't seem to get anything but the view, rather than the clicked element.

Answer (score 21):

You can call `this.get('element')` to get the actual element.

See: [Ember View Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_element)

Answer (score 2):

I know is an old question but since views are deprecated (and if you are not needing this for a component), you can pass the action to the dom onclick event and get the event js object in the last parameter of the action.

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066157/2726189

hope it helps

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now a VERY old question but we are removing jQuery and used the following vanilla JS to get the DOM element

```
document.querySelector(`#${this.element.id}`);
```

along with a `{{did-insert this.functionThatCallsTheAboveCode}}` on the component's wrapping div.