# Pass a reference of the clicked DOM element to the action handler in Ember

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I have a set of buttons whose state I wish to toggle with a class `active`. If I had a single button, then I would bind the `active` class to a controller property and toggle that property in the click handler:

```
<button {{action 'toggle'}} class="{{active}}">model.title</button>

actions: {
  toggle: function() {
    this.set('active', true);
  }
}
```

But I have multiple buttons, so I am not sure what I can bind. It would be useful if I could pass a reference to the clicked button to the action handler, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <button {{action 'toggle' referenceToButton}}>model.title</button>
{{/each}}

actions: {
  toggle: function(buttonReference) {
    // add `active` class to buttonReference
  }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't the model-item what you want to pass and not the button?

Then your toggle can just set an attribute on the item which you [bind to your button class](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-class-names/).

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <button {{bind-attr class="item.isActive:active"}} {{action 'toggle' item}}>model.title</button>
{{/each}}

actions: {
  toggle: function(item) {
    item.set('isActive', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if it's a checkbox and I want to know if it's checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 16):

Even though the poster got the answer he wanted, I thought I'd post an answer to what I believe was the intention of the original question:

**How to get a reference the clicked DOM element from an action?**    since I came here looking for an answer to that question and didn't find it.

I can't find a way to get the actual element, but you can get the root view element (which wraps the elements defined in the template) via `this`:

template:

`<button {{action 'toggle' this}}>model.title</button>`

controller, view, component:

```
actions: {
  toggle: function(event) {
    // Get element (as in the return value of document.getElementById(id))
    var viewElements = event.element;
    var elementsInTemplate = viewElements.children;
    var button = viewElements.getElementsByTagName('button');
    //also can use getElementsByClassName, use jQuery etc.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just another answer...

if you put the action in the onclick (or any other dom event) you will get the "event" javascript object in the last parameter (so you can use event.target to get and manipulate the object)

Template:

```
<button onclick={{action 'toggle' model.title}}>model.title</button>
```

Route or controller:

```
actions: {
  toggle (title, event) {
    // TODO: use title 
    let element = Ember.$(event.target);
    element.toggleClass("active");

    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oddly, if you use this method, you cannot refer to an action farther up the responder chain. For example, if you have an `openModal` action in your application route, `<a {{action 'openModal'}}>` will bubble up to that application route. But, `<a onclick={{action 'openModal'}}>` it will not. It won't even display the template without an error. In this case, `openModal` must be defined on the direct controller of the template.

Comment: It turns out that using `onclick={{action 'toggle'}}` will turn out to be just like `onclick=function() { ... }`. So you will have standard dom bubbling but no ember action bubbling. Here's some discussion on that very topic:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14867#issuecomment-280341753

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce `active` property to `items`

```
{{#each item as |model|}}
  <button {{action 'toggle' model}} class={{if model.active 'active'}}>{{model.title}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

if `active=true` then `active` class will be applied to button.

```
actions: {
  toggle: function(buttonReference) {
    buttonReference.set('active', true);
  }
}
```

To answer the question title `Pass a reference of the clicked DOM element to the action handler in Ember`.

1.If you are using component, then you can define any of this [list of event names](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#toc_event-names) in component and that is designed to receive native `event` object.
eg.,
`{{my-button model=model}}`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
 click(event){
  //oncliking on this componen will trigger this function
  return true; //to bubble this event up
 }
})
```

2.If you are using html tag like `button` then you need to assign a (closure) action to an inline event handler.

```
{{#each item as |model|}}
      <button onclick={{action 'toggle' model}}>{{model.title}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

In actions hash `toggle` function will always receive native browser `event` object as the last argument.

```
actions:{
 toggle(model,event){

 }
}
```

In this `<button {{action 'toggle' model}}>{{model.title}}</button>` format, action `toggle` will not receive `event` object,

Explained really well in ember guide https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/handling-events/#toc_sending-actions